# Слитно или раздельно: "по месту нахождения"?

Tags: орфография

Как правильно писать — слитно или раздельно: "по месту нахождения рабочих мест" или "по местонахождению рабочих мест"?

Answer (score 2):

„Местонахождение“ — тяжёлый канцеляризм. Словарь предлагает такие примеры на это слово:
*„Местонахождение полезных ископаемых. Определить местонахождение подводной лодки. Сообщить о местонахождении альпинистов“.*
Мы видим, что это о людях и военных объектах.

Я бы написал *„по месту нахождения рабочих мест“* (нужно ведь не слово „местонахождение“, а слово „место“ в смысле „по месту, где находятся рабочие места“).

Comment: Согласна с предыдущим ответом.

Answer (score 0):

Раздельно нужно писать

Answer (score 0):

Можно и слитно, и раздельно. Но здесь лучше написать слитно, чтобы не так бросалось в глаза использование рядом двух однокоренных слов (это не рекомендуется, нужно подобрать синоним).

Answer (score 0):

"По расположению рабочих мест".
Вообще-то неплохо бы всю фразу видеть.

Answer (score 0):

Оба варианта формально подходят. "Слитно или раздельно" — ложная дилемма.

Один вариант использует сочетание из нескольких слов — ясно, что здесь раздельно.
Другой вариант использует одно составное слово, ясно, что слитно.

Но это грамматический подход, какой оборот более уместен семантически, без контекста определить трудно.

Если брать самую очевидную семантику, я бы выбрал вариант №3: тот, что у пользователя Niemand, избегая канцеляризма.